# function to find the maximum number of pipes

Tags: c, operating-system, pipe, file-descriptor

How can I find the maximum possible number of pipes using a c program. How does it work on operating system level? 
I guess the maximum possible number of pipes will be determined by the maximum entries that the file descriptor table can have. Is it correct? What is your insight?

Comment: The answer will depend on the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Each pipe takes two FDs. So the answer is the maximum number of FDs, less those in use (e.g. STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR), divided by two.

To find the maximum number of FDs, use

```
ulimit -n
```

Apart from that, there will most likely be a higher operating system limit. You do not say what operating system you are using, but on Linux I believe it's a kernel compile option (that's from memory). In no case can the number of FDs exceed `INT_MAX`.

I see you want a C function to read this. I suggest you use `getrlimit` passing `RLIMIT_NOFILE`